# Dynamically Adding and Changing overlays using Jquery tools

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-tools

I am using Jquery tools and I need to be able to dynamically add or change overlays, But i cant seem to get it to work. Basically, when I get html from a ajax call, i want to remove an overlay, then add another. In some cases I would need to add an overlay all together. I recreated the problem in this jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/WK9wk/1/

If you click on the pictures the overlay shows. Clicking on the button, will dynamically change the overlay. After that, the overlay no longer displays.

Comment: I couldn't see any ajax call in the fiddle? Have you included it or want to know a solution?

Comment: yea I forgot to save it, Here is the updated link- http://jsfiddle.net/WK9wk/1/

Comment: also, Im emulating an ajax call when you click on the button.

Comment: Yea, im looking for a solution

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm a little confused. Do you want the overlay just for one element? After button press(ajax return). What should happen? Shoudl the image be overlayed already or wait until you click on the div to get the overlay? (Two images to start with : Is that just an example?)

Comment: Yea, there are two just because of the example. From the beginning both overlays work fine. Now when I click on the button which replaces the second overlay, the second overlay stops working. I'm trying to figure out why and what I can do to make it work

Comment: I have never used overlay before. But this is what I suspect : i) Once an overlay is bound to an element, it cannot be re-bound if already bound. ii) Because you are removing the div and replacing it, this doesn't rebound the overlay to the 2nd image (which is to be clicked). QUES : Why do you want to replace the whole div and why not just everything under it? Can't your ajax return only the stuff which is to be changed iso of a larger bulk. If you'd like to replace only what is inside the div, it works smoothly.

Comment: For example this : http://jsfiddle.net/WK9wk/8/ Or wrap this in another html element which is to be referenced by the image click (which is set up for overlay) if the response ajax cannot be changed.

Comment: I considered that, But for what I am doing it isnt ideal. I am swapping multiple overlays, and adding and removing them. You are right in that I need to find a way to rebind the img to another element.